# How to check if a parent entity contains sub entities in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have created a model in **Core Data** as given below :-

[image]

It shows that there are **Categories** that contain **Contacts** that further contain **Phone Numbers** and **Email Addresses** .

Now I need to know how will I check if the Parent entity has various sub entities in the CategoryTable ?

How do I perform a *fetch request* that will separate the parent entities from the sub entities and tell me which sub entities are of which parent entities ?

What kind of *filter predicate* should be used in this case ?

Comment: Your question's description isn't very clear to me. What are you trying to achieve in practice? Can you give a practical example of what is the final result you want?

Comment: @GianlucaTranchedone The final result I want is an array containing the parent entities and various arrays containing the sub entities that relate to the parent entity array...

Comment: That is still not very clear.  Perhaps a bullet list of the results you want as you are talking about *multiple* filters/predicates to produce your results.

Answer (score 0):

The Category model you have allows you to create a hierarchy of infinite depth so a parent object can also be a child object.

You need to traverse the hierarchy using the following approach:

Root level objects should always have parent = nil so your tope level predicate would simply be "parent == nil".

Then for each root object you can get its children by simply using "parent == %@", parentObject

You may want to use a UITableView to show each level in the hierarchy and so just add a property in the tableViewController that contains the parentObject and when you select a row push a new instance of the viewController.